# Lighttpd: configure mod_scgi to be case insensitive

Tags: lighttpd, case-insensitive, scgi

I have the following `lighttpd.conf`:

```
server.document-root = "/var/www/root" 
server.modules = ( "mod_scgi" )
server.port = 80

server.username = "www" 
server.groupname = "www"

mimetype.assign = (
  ".htm" => "text/html",
  ".html" => "text/html", 
  ".txt" => "text/plain",
  ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".png" => "image/png",
  ".myfile" => "text/html",
  ".zhtml" => "text/html"
)

index-file.names = ( "index.html" )

server.protocol-http11 = "enable"
server.error-handler-404 = "/error-404.php"

scgi.server = ( 
    "/infodesk" => ( "127.0.0.1" => ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9123, "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable", "check-local" => "disable" ) )
)
```

When requesting `http://192.168.0.42/infodesk` I get the correct CGI. But when requesting e.g. `http://192.168.0.42/InfoDesk` I get an Error 404.

Is there any way to configure mod_scgi to be case insensitive?

I searched the lighttpd docs and configurations but couldn't find a thing. The source code of mod_scgi is ok to read and understand, but I didn't find a line where the CGI-URI is handlend or compared or so.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I solved it.

In lighttpd-1.4.33 source `mod_scgi.c` (beginning line 2715):

```
/* check if extension matches */
for (k = 0; k < p->conf.exts->used; k++) {
    size_t ct_len;
    scgi_extension *ext = p->conf.exts->exts[k];

    if (ext->key->used == 0) continue;

    ct_len = ext->key->used - 1;

    if (s_len < ct_len) continue;

    /* check extension in the form "/scgi_pattern" */
    if (*(ext->key->ptr) == '/') {
        if (strncmp(fn->ptr, ext->key->ptr, ct_len) == 0) {
            extension = ext;
            break;
        }
    } else if (0 == strncmp(fn->ptr + s_len - ct_len, ext->key->ptr, ct_len)) {
        /* check extension in the form ".fcg" */
        extension = ext;
        break;
    }
}
```

replace the `strncmp()` with a `strcasecmp()` and delete param `ct_len`.

Now the CGI-URI `http://192.168.0.42/infodesk` will be handled the same as `http://192.168.0.42/InfoDesk`.